# How to run protractor to validate CHROME on AWS

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, protractor

I'm building a SaaS solution using AngularJS / JBOSS, hosted on a AWS EC2 instance; all our functionality is covered by unit and e2e tests. All the tests run fine locally. We can't figure out how to run them on AWS. Our AWS installation includes a headless CHROME, installed according to [these instructions](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com/2013/02/setting-up-chrome-firefox-ec2-selenium-java.html):

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Set up chrome/firefox in linux based x86_64 EC2 instance
2. Launch *webdriver-manager start*
3. On a separate terminal window, launch protractor

**Observed Behavior**
 1. The following error is shown on the webdriver terminal:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
06:41:15.140 WARN - Exception thrown
```

**Expected Behavior**
 1. The protractor test is executed without errors

**Additional resources**:
 1. Protractor configuration file

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

    specs: ['../test/e2e/**/*.js'],

    // A base URL for your application under test. Calls to browser.get()
    // with relative paths will be prepended with this.
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/markodojo_solution/#/a3bc8692-5af4-4a4d-b21b-4e6f87dc2a32',

    // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        isVerbose: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },

    //Options to output testreuslts in xml format
    onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
      new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true));
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Just checking, but... did you install `libgconf-2`?

Comment: No I did not. I'll do it now and report back.

Comment: I was not able to install libconf-2, yum install ligcong-2 yields a no package available message. Someone suggested I try to install gconf2 but unfortunately I get the same error. I also tried all possible alternatives that came up from net searches, to no avail!

Comment: Hi.. stuck at the same point you were a year back :)
Any pointers on how you proceeded?

I'm getting the same error:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

**Go with Headless Chrome option**

This greatly simplifies the workflow and having to use more system resources.

Follow the broad steps below:

1. Chrome install. Assuming you already have Chrome installed there. However if not following [steps to install Chrome on linux EC2](https://medium.com/@davidkadlec/installing-google-chrome-on-amazon-linux-ec2-d1cb6aa37f28)
2. Change your protractor options to something like below. The important thing is `--headless`. Additionally keep in mind that headless mode requires the browser size be specified upfront:-

   ```
     chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
      }
   ```